# Java - cannot step into a function when function is called within an assert

Tags: java, assert, skip, breakpoints, step-into

So I noticed while debugging a Netbeans Java application when a function call is used in an assert function, you cannot hit a breakpoint within that function or step into that function.

At first I thought it had to do something to do with using an overridden function and my overridden function not being called, but I confirmed that is not what is going on. It still gets called, but cannot be stepped into.

Here is the snippet that I tried:

```
public class Example
{
    public static boolean blah()
    {
        System.out.println("Executing");    //**Breakpoint here
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        assert(blah());    //Cannot step into or hit breakpoint on this line.
        blah();            //Can here.
    }
}
```

Anybody have any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, assertions are disabled at runtime.

Perhaps your debugging JVM does not have assertions enabled.

To enable assertions, specify the `-enableassertions` (or -`ea`) switch for your NetBeans debugging JVM parameters. Even though assertions are compiled into the bytecode, they won't execute without this switch.

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable) for more

Comment: So if the assertion was false then it wouldn't matter (as if it wasn't there anyway)?

I see, even in my own example, "Executing" wasn't even being printed. Hah, Thanks. (Original code was much more hence didn't realize it wasn't running at all) 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, just maybe, every `assert` statement is optimized out in this build?  Are you sure your print statement is executed twice?

The whole point of `assert` is that you can tell the compiler to just ignore what's inside when you want to optimize your code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you assume that?The `blah` method is not just a `while(false)` or `while(true)` pseudomethod to be optimized out by the compiler (assuming assertions are enabled)

Comment: No it wasn't printed twice, my mistake in migrating to a simple example. xD